# Boost how to write edge's weight in graphviz?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

With boost, I am trying to write in graphviz format a very large and dense graph which is an `adjacency_matrix`. The graph itself : `boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float>, boost::no_property>`.

I searched in StackOverflow, Google, and either I did not understand the code or it was a LABEL writer and not a WEIGHT writer.

My boost version is the 1.72.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label writers are [`PropertyWriter`s](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/graph/doc/write-graphviz.html#concept:PropertyWriter) just as well. `PropertyWriters` are used to write weights (or any other edge/vertex attribute).

However, I highly recommend using `dynamic_properties` to simplify the process. Here's [20+ usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+write_graphviz_dp) I have on this site.

Here's the simplest application on `ajacency_matrix` that I can think of:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d25e7988565d235)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using EP = boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, float>;
using G  = boost::adjacency_matrix<boost::undirectedS, boost::no_property, EP>;

int main() {
    G g(5);

    add_edge(1, 2, 3.5f, g);
    add_edge(2, 3, 4.5f, g);

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g));
    dp.property("weight",  get(boost::edge_weight,  g));
    boost::write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g, dp);
}
```

Printing:

```
graph G {
0;
1;
2;
3;
4;
2--1  [weight=3.5];
3--2  [weight=4.5];
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but in my case it does not work at all… And I'm even more sorry that I can not put the code here right now…

Comment: Only one thing to do: eliminate sources of trouble. Reduce your code until you have nothing else left to explain the discrepancy. While you do this, you will 100% guaranteed run into the deciding factor, and you have a better question to ask.